# Android 11+ device all file permission issue

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play

In my Application i want to upload file(pdf from downloads and other folders) from mobile to server.

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
```

Everything working fine. but after uploaded google playstore app continuously rejected because of

**Issue found: Not a core feature(Use of All Files Access Permission)**
The feature you identified that is dependent on this permission does not appear to be critical to the core functionality of your app.
Core functionality is defined as the main purpose of the app. Without this core functionality, the app is "broken" or rendered unusable.

what is the alternative for this? without this permission file not able to upload Android 11 and Android 12 devices.

Answer (score 0):

Your app is rejected because this is not your Core Feature or you couldn't define you use case to Google properly.

You can only get **MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** if you app is from one of the below category.

`File managers`
`Backup and restore apps`
`Anti-virus apps`
`Document management apps`
`On-device file search`
`Disk and file encryption`
`Device-to-device data migration` [Reference](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files)

If your app is from any above category then define it properly in from it will get approved otherwise follow below solution.

Alternative for this which you should use is SAF ([Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider)) or you can use ([Mediastore API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore))